# fill an array only with nested object literals

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-literal

In this code i intend to find all the nested object literals in a parent object.One of my nested object has an array called places as its own property.I have a recursive function called `getObjNum` which goes through every property and finds nested object literals inside parent object.

In my Parent object there are three nested object literals.One of them has an array as property.So `container` array which is supposed to store all the found nested object literals must have 3 indexes.But array places also included as fourth index to container array.I found

```
typeof(array)=='object' returns true;
arr instanceof Object also returns true;
```

How can i prevent the place array to be inserted to container array along with other object literals??

[image]

```
var getValue;
  var parentObj = {
     parentProp: 10,
       childObj: {
           childProp: 20,
                    grandChildObj: {
                       y: {
                          z:'lol',
                          places:['newyork','canada','dhaka']
                       }
                    }
                }
      }


var arr=[];
var container=[];
var count=0;

function getObjNum(obj){

      var prop=Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
      for(i=0;i<prop.length;i++){
          if(typeof(obj[prop[i]])=='object'){
            container.push(obj[prop[i]]);
            count++;
            getObjNum(obj[prop[i]]);
          }

      }
}
getObjNum(parentObj);

console.log(container);
```

Comment: Check for array using [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)?

Comment: You might also note that `arr instanceof Array` returns `true` while `obj instanceof Array` is `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can use `instanceof Array` to check if an object is an array or not, like so:

```
function getChildObjects(obj, returnArr) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function (arr, key) {
        var prop = obj[key];
        if (typeof prop === 'object' && !(prop instanceof Array)) {
            arr.push(prop);
            arr = getChildObjects(prop, arr);
        }
        return arr; 
    }, returnArr || []);
}

var parentObj = {
    parentProp: 10,
    childObj: {
        childProp: 20,
        grandChildObj: {
            y: {
                z:'lol',
                places:['newyork','canada','dhaka']
            }
        }
    }
};

var childs = getChildObjects(parentObj);

console.log(childs, childs.length);
```